# Mechanize returning robot.txt despite being set to ignore

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize, scrape

I've encountered a few websites that when I've attempted to extract code return the ROBOTS metatag, and continue to do so even when attempting to use Mechanize. As an example:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open("http://myanimelist.net/anime.php?letter=B")
response = br.response().read()
```

I've tried setting headers and setting other handles, but never get a response that isnt the ROBOTS metatag.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Edit:

Attempting the suggested headers below:

```
import mechanize
url = "http://myanimelist.net/anime.php?letter=B"

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders=[('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'),
       ('Host', 'myanimelist.net'),
       ('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'),
       ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, sdch'),
       ('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6'),
       ('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0'),
       ('Connection', 'keep-alive')]
br.open(url)
response = br.response().read()
print response
```

I still get the same ROBOTs metatag. Am I adding the headers wrong, or am I merely getting stuck at the CAPTCHA?

Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand [`set_handle_robots()`](https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/blob/068fc642ae705aa0c71732db4b77d342e5b23628/mechanize/_useragent.py#L242) is only about following the rules listed in `robots.txt`:

```
def set_handle_robots(self, handle):
    """Set whether to observe rules from robots.txt."""
```

Which you, by the way, should respect and be a good web-scraping citizen.

---

They are, though, very strict about web-scraping - you are getting set behind captcha easily - be careful. FYI, they are protected by [`Incapsula`](http://www.incapsula.com/website-security/) which has an advanced `Bot Protection`:

> Using advanced client classification technology, crowdsourcing and
>   reputation-based techniques, Incapsula distinguishes between "good"
>   and "bad" bot traffic. This lets you block scrapers, vulnerability
>   scanners and comment spammers that overload your servers and steal
>   your content, while allowing search engines and other legitimate
>   services to freely access your website.

Another important "FYI", quote from the ["Terms of Use"](http://www.craveonline.com/termsofuse?site=www.MyAnimeList.net):

> You agree not to use or launch any automated system, including without
>   limitation, "robots," "spiders," "offline readers," etc. , that
>   accesses the Service in a manner that sends more request messages to
>   the Company servers than a human can reasonably produce in the same
>   period of time by using a conventional on-line web browser, and you
>   agree not to aggregate or collate any of the content available through
>   the Service for use elsewhere. You also agree not to collect or
>   harvest any personally identifiable information, including account or
>   profile names, from the Service nor to use the communication systems
>   provided by the Service for any commercial solicitation purposes.

Which leads to my actual answer: there is an [official `API`](http://myanimelist.net/modules.php?go=api) provided, use it. Stay on the legal side.